# Conditional variable and thread context switch

Tags: c++, multithreading

We have two threads. Thread A and Thread B.

If thread A is waiting on a condition using a condition variable, which is suppose to be satisfied (notify) by thread B.

My question is while thread A is waiting on the conditional variable, if the CPU context switches out the thread A.
During this time if thread B calls notify on the conditional variable, will thread A get the notification when the CPU schedules the  thread A next or is the notification lost since thread A was not running when the notification was issued.

Comment: Don't overthink it. Read the specification for condition variables. When a thread has blocked in a wait a subsequent call to notify will wake it up.

Comment: No, the notification is not lost. Otherwise condition variables will be utterly and completely useless.

Comment: Thanks Pete.
Agreed Sam the notification should not be lost. But then is it stored in a queue and when thread A is live again the queued up notification is delivered to it?

Comment: @4d.coder A is typically moved from waiting-on-signal to waiting-on-mutex (you know, the one that was latched prior to entering into the cv-wait that started this whole mental exercise?). The underlying mechanics, however, aren't as important as ensuring the actual behavior honors the standard as describe by POSIX.1c, which is worth reading more than anything else at this point.

Comment: Actually, the standard library is provided so that you can blissfully ignore the existence of context switches. There need not be any argument about how the CPU or OS works, condition variable as defined by C++ will do as it promised: wake up when its notified.